# Why does this yacc code generate shift/reduce conflicts

Tags: yacc

I don't know why the following code will generate shift / reduce conflicts

```
primary_no_literal_expression
    : IDENTIFIER 
    {
        $$ = mioc_create_identifier_expression($1);
    }
    | IDENTIFIER LC RC      // shift/reduce conflicts
    {

    }
    | function_no_argument_call_expression
    | function_with_argument_call_expression
    | primary_no_literal_expression slice_index_expression
    | primary_no_literal_expression DOT IDENTIFIER
    | primary_no_literal_expression DOT IDENTIFIER LP RP
    | primary_no_literal_expression DOT function_with_argument_call_expression
    ;
```

show State 53 conflicts: 1 shift/reduce

y.output in state 53

```
state 53

   95 primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER .
   96                              | IDENTIFIER . LC RC
  103 function_no_argument_call_expression: IDENTIFIER . LP RP
  107 function_with_argument_list: IDENTIFIER . LP argument_list RP

    LP  shift, and go to state 105
    LC  shift, and go to state 106

    LC        [reduce using rule 95 (primary_no_literal_expression)]
    $default  reduce using rule 95 (primary_no_literal_expression)
```

```
state 106

   96 primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER LC . RC

    RC  shift, and go to state 159
...
state 159

   96 primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER LC RC .

    $default  reduce using rule 96 (primary_no_literal_expression)
```

rule 95

```
   95 primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER
   96                              | IDENTIFIER LC RC
   97                              | function_no_argument_call_expression
   98                              | function_with_argument_call_expression
   99                              | primary_no_literal_expression slice_index_expression
  100                              | primary_no_literal_expression DOT IDENTIFIER
  101                              | primary_no_literal_expression DOT IDENTIFIER LP RP
  102                              | primary_no_literal_expression DOT function_with_argument_call_expression
```

LC        [reduce using rule 95 (primary_no_literal_expression)]
primary_no_literal_expression rule is "IDENTIFIER LC RC"(rule 95) Why just read LC to reduce？

full code

y.output https://controlc.com/56d66aea/fullscreen.php?hash=4f3bc1c214e1f3347b3a64df69a9b519&toolbar=true&linenum=false

test.y https://controlc.com/04d49e1b/fullscreen.php?hash=6dde9e69b9ea5873ff6ac234474a5927&toolbar=true&linenum=false

Comment: Are you sure about  `primary_expression_list assignment_operator right_expression ` ? While it was a decade since I heard about yacc, I think your conflict is because the parser can't tell if `a, b = 1` should be `(a), (b=1)` or `(a, b) = 1`.  And I don't know the language you are building, but multiple assignation (`a=1, b=2`) is not what you are doing here.

Comment: Yes I need ```primary_expression_list assignment_operator right_expression```, but my modification to ```primary_expression assignment_operator right_expression``` did not eliminate **State 53 conflicts: 1 shift / reduce**

Comment: Delete ```primary_expression``` its ```|primary_no_literal_expression```and```| DOT primary_no_literal_expression``` can eliminate the ```primary_no_literal_expression``` its ```| IDENTIFIER LC RC``` Conflicts I do not know where the problem lies?

Answer (score 2):

The shift/reduce conflict comes becuase there is some context where `primary_no_literal_expression` is used (on the right hand side of some rule), where it can be followed by an `LC` token.  That means after seeing an `IDENTIFIER` token, when the next token (lookahead) is `LC` the parser doesn't know whether it should shift the `LC` to (to eventuallay match the `primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER LC RC` rule) or reduce the `primary_no_literal_expression: IDENTIFIER` rule (to match whatever it is that allows an `LC` after a `primary_no_literal_expression`

You need to find that rule and figure out what to do about it -- either get rid of one of the rules (if things are ambiguous), or figure out how to know which rule to match (based on additional lookahead and/or lexer feedback, or something else)

In your case the culprit (one of them, at least) is probably the rule `if_statement: IF logical_or_expression block` since a `logical_or_expression` can expand to (or end with) a `primary_no_literal_expression`, and a `block` can start with an `LC`.  So the conflict is telling you the parser can't tell where an expression like this ends, and the block begins.

Comment: Thank you very much, as you said, I found the reason.